# Cache resource on startup of express

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, express

I am wondering if someone could help me point out how to cache a resource in express/node on startup of the web server. The myCol.find is very expensive, so I would like to just run it once on startup, and cache the result for all subsequent requests. Is there a startup step I can tie into? Can this be done synchronously before the server starts accepting requests?

I have the code below, but would like to reference a cached variable instead of the mongo db

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

var myCol = require('./customModule');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/test/:testId', function(req, res) {
    myCol.find(function(err, allResults) {
        res.json(allResults);
    });
});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you just need to make sure your server starts listening after you've fetched your results through `myCol.find()`:

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

var myCol = require('./customModule');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var router = express.Router();

var myResultsCache;

router.get('/test/:testId', function(req, res) {
    res.send(myResultsCache);
});

app.use('/api', router);

myCol.find(function(err, allResults) {
    //you should add some error handling here
    myResultsCache = allResults;
    app.listen(port);
});
```

Comment: Yes. I like this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the order of `myCol.find` and the route handler, so that the relevant code would be:

```
myCol.find(function(error, results) {
  if (error) throw error;
  router.get('/test/:testId', function (request, response) {
    response.json(results);
  });
});
```

This is still asynchronous, but the server would only be able to respond after the `find` operation has been done.